# Finding Fmax in FPGA design without adding extra cycle

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus-ii

I'm trying to find the Fmax of my VHDL design in Quartus II. I know that you need to have a register-to-register path for finding the Fmax. However, when I register the input, another cycle is added. I want the code to be 1 cycle and still show Fmax.

Code with registered inputs:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity generic_RBSD is

    generic(
        BIN_WIDTH : integer := 4
    );
    port(
        bin_input : in signed(BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        RBSD_output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        clk : in STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;
architecture behavioral of generic_RBSD is
    signal a : signed(BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
        variable bin : signed(BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        variable RBSD : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            a <= bin_input;
            if bin_input(BIN_WIDTH-1) = '1' then
                bin := -a;
            else
                bin := a;
            end if;
            for i in 0 to BIN_WIDTH-1 loop
                if bin(i) = '1' then
                    RBSD(2*i+1 downto 2*i) := "11";
                else
                    RBSD(2*i+1 downto 2*i) := "10";
                end if;
            end loop;
            if bin_input(BIN_WIDTH-1) = '1' then
                RBSD := not RBSD;
            end if;
        end if;
        RBSD_output <= RBSD;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Without registered inputs (works, but doesn't show Fmax):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity generic_RBSD is

    generic(
        BIN_WIDTH : integer := 4
    );
    port(
        bin_input : in signed(BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        RBSD_output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        clk : in STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;
architecture behavioral of generic_RBSD is
    signal a : signed(BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
        variable bin : signed(BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        variable RBSD : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*BIN_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if bin_input(BIN_WIDTH-1) = '1' then
                bin := -bin_input;
            else
                bin := bin_input;
            end if;
            for i in 0 to BIN_WIDTH-1 loop
                if bin(i) = '1' then
                    RBSD(2*i+1 downto 2*i) := "11";
                else
                    RBSD(2*i+1 downto 2*i) := "10";
                end if;
            end loop;
            if bin_input(BIN_WIDTH-1) = '1' then
                RBSD := not RBSD;
            end if;
        end if;
        RBSD_output <= RBSD;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: If you don't have an internal register-to-register path, then you need to specify the external input and output timing constraints explicitly. It's been a while since I last used Quartus, so you'll have to read the documentation to get the details on how to do this. It involves creating a Synopsis Design Constraints (`.sdc`) file, using either a text editor or the IDE.

Comment: If you want to get Fmax, you need to add registers. Otherwise you are looking for Tdelay. The Quartus report should show 4 values if the paths exist: input delay (pin -> FF), output delay (FF -> pin), Fmax/longest path (FF -> FF) and input-output delay (pin -> pin).

Comment: But adding registers adds extra cycles which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get the timing:

1) Create a wrapper for the whole module, that registers the inputs and outputs and have the tools calculate Fmax of system+wrapper. Although I would consider it troublesome for an reusable IPcore to claim a high fmax and then find it unregistered and dumping a load of combinatorial logic either side on the user.

2) Mark the pins of your design as virtual pins. See e.g. [Does setting pins as virtual affect timing?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79726/does-setting-pins-as-virtual-affect-timing) Here quartus analyses timing assuming your inputs feed from 'nearby' registers and outputs drive nearby rgeisters, which will let you get a decent timing estimate without being penalised to carry the IO signals all the way into perhiphery I/O pads (and save you writing timing constraints for the same).